# Find a target value in an unsorted array of integers by performing additions of integers

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

Following is an interview question asked by 'Amazon' to me. I still haven't come up with a optimized solution.

**Problem Statement:**
Given an unsorted array of integers n. **Return 'true' if the addition** of any integers from that array **matches** with the **target value** else **return false**.

**Note:**

```
   1)'n' could be 1000 or 10,000.
   2) Target value could be 'negative'
   3) It may be addition of any 'k' integers (not only two) , where k<=n.
```

**Test Condition:**

```
    i/p:- Array A[]= {6,7,3,0,12,-5,-6,100}
    Target =  8
    o/p:- TRUE        
As, 6+7+(-5)=8
```

If we try to do it linearly or normally it will take **O(2^n) time complexity**.
So I am looking for any method or algorithm which will optimized this problem more.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Addition of any TWO integers" do you mean? or any number?

Comment: If I'm hearing you right, you were asked to solve the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete. So you can't reasonably be expected to do a lot better than exponential time or pseudopolynomial time.

Comment: If it is a pair of integers, I think you mean O(n^2) time, not O(2^n).

Comment: Heh, my answer would be something like: O(N^2), and N can be 1,000 or 10,000 ... 10,000*10,000 = 100M = 5 milliseconds on a desktop CPU. If that's troubling, it means you want to solve this rather uninteresting problem 200 times per second -- which is unlikely to happen. Sometimes, brute-force is just good enough.

Comment: It's sad that only two people understand such a clear question. Everybody besides @nneonneo and kasavbere is way off. Do people read questions anymore? Or do they simply think they know so much better?

Comment: @KarthikT No. It may be the addition of 'k' numbers ,where k <=n

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The subset-sum problem is a well-known NP-complete problem. Here, I'm going to assume that you are looking for any set of numbers to sum to the target (if you're actually looking for only two numbers, there's a five-line solution using a counting hashtable which runs in O(n) time).

There are two basic approaches. The first is just to test every possible subsequence. As you've already observed, that takes O(2<sup>n</sup>) time (exponential), which is intractable if n is 1000.

The second is to keep track of what sums are obtainable from prefixes of the list. This is a very simple approach, and works well if the integers are bounded. By way of example, if the input is n k-bit integers, it has computational complexity O(2<sup>k</sup>n<sup>2</sup>) (pseudopolynomial): the biggest the sums can get is 2<sup>k</sup>n, so the table has at most 2<sup>k</sup>n<sup>2</sup> entries. This is a typical dynamic programming approach, where the subproblem is `T[s][k] = (A[1..k] has a subsequence summing to s)`, and the final solution is given by `T[target][n]`.

Here's a solution in Python implementing this:

```
def subset_sum(A, target):
    T = {0} # T[s][0] = (TRUE iff s == 0)
    for i in A:
        T |= {x + i for x in T}
    return target in T
```

Examples:

```
>>> subset_sum([-5,6,7,1,0,12,5,-6,100], 13)
True
>>> subset_sum([95, -120, 22, 14491], 13)
False
```

---

*Bonus*: If you're curious, here's a solution to the pair-sum problem. It runs in O(n) time and tells you if the array has two numbers summing to the target.

```
from collections import Counter
def pair_sum(A, t):
    C = Counter(A)
    for k,v in C.iteritems():
        if t == k+k and v > 1: return True # k is in the array twice
        elif t != k+k and t-k in C: return True
    return False
```

Examples:

```
>>> pair_sum([3,3,3,4], 13)
False
>>> pair_sum([3,3,3,10], 13)
True
>>> pair_sum([7,7,2], 14)
True
>>> pair_sum([7,14,2], 14)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** This answer is still informative so I'm keeping it, but after OP's edit it is less relevant.

Here is how I would solve it in `O(n)` runtime complexity and `O(n)` space complexity using a concept called 'Hashing'. (Where n is the size of the array)

Let's call the number I'd like to get `d`

First I would create some sort of `HashTable` (a key value store). 
HashMaps have `O(1)` insert, get and contains. You can read about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Then I would put every object in the cell d-object in the hash map. Before I check the next number x I'd check if the hash map contains a value at cell x. If it does we've found our match.

Here is some pseudo code (I think this is better for a general answer than C code)

```
CheckIfTwoNumbersComplementTo(d,arr)
    map <-- new HashTable
    for each number x in Arr
        if(map contains a key for x)
            return true
        else
            add d-x to map if it is not already in map
    return false
```

Comment: Nice, but I bet your hash table is going to take up more than O(n) space.  To get effectively constant-time operations, you'll need to allocate space for many hash buckets, won't you?

Comment: My HashTable can be implemented in _exactly_ O(n) space. I can simply allocate an array of size [n] and use the indexes directly as keys :) I did not want to specifically suggest that in the answer because I wanted to keep the solution as general as possible.

Comment: This works only if the question is corrected to say: ".. if the addition of /two/ integers ..". Furthermore, exactly `O(n)` doesn't make any sense, did you mean exactly `n` space ? But then that is plain false, given your own example. Array allows for duplicates, so suppose we want to find the sum 1000, and we have an array of one thousand `1`s. Mad collision with your scheme happens (and the algorithm doesn't work in this case either, since it is no longer about summing two integers to find a given value).

Comment: I assumed OP was talking about any _two_ integers. I meant n space and n steps. The minute I get a duplicate I'm done so I don't care about duplicates

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you are miscalculating things here. Suppose you have an array `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .. (a lot of 1s) .., -1}` and the target value is `0`. You will be adding `0-1 = -1` a lot of times here, and looking up on that map many times. Your simple scheme provides so many collisions that this is now `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Again, I do not understand why I should care about duplicates, I don't really have to store -1 a million times, I'll edit my answer to clarify though that's a good point.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum so can we agree that this is not `n` space, maybe `O(n)` space with a not too low constant. You should care about duplicates as the question stands. If it is corrected to say /any two/ integers, then you don't need. If it is corrected to say /any three/ integers, now you need again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23745/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-mmgp)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Problem can extend till the addition of 'k' numbers, where k<=n. If your any addition matches target value you are done, just return with 'True'.

Answer (score 0):

What about sort the array, and for each element calculate the pair necessary to the target value and search for it ? that would make the cost of sorting + plus each binary search.

Comment: So that would be O(n log n) time.